# C++ MySQL, using connection established in one function in other function within the same class

Tags: c++, mysql, connection

Simple code below:

```
class A{

    MySQL *conn;
    int query;
public:
    bool one(string fpServerName, string fpUserName, string fpPassword, string fpDatabase){
    conn = mysql_init(&mysql);
    conn = mysql_real_connect(&mysql, fpServerName.c_str(), fpUserName.c_str(),   fpPassword.c_str(), fpDatabase.c_str(), 0, NULL, 0);
    if (!conn)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
    }

    two(string fpSQL){
        query = mysql_query(conn, fpSQL.c_str());
    }

    A(){}
    }

    int main(){
    A obj;
    obj.one("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "users");
    obj.two(fpSQL);
    }
```

When I'm calling one("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "users") function it connects to DB. Now I would like to use conn in two(fpSQL), but unfortunatelly program crashes in query = mysql_query(conn, fpSQL.c_str()); Is there anything I'm missing? Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The program is crashing because your **conn** variable is nullptr

Try to check the conn variable in this way:

```
void two(string fpSQL){
    if(nullptr!=conn){
        query = mysql_query(conn, fpSQL.c_str());
    }
}
```

Another thing is that, the function **one** returns a boolean value that you are not checking, change the main function in this way:

```
int main(){
    A obj;
    if(obj.one("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "users")){
        obj.two(fpSQL);
        // Close connection here
    }
}
```

Remember to close the connection at the end of main.